# Matplotlib Animation plotting the same thing for every frame

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to recreate the animation in [this](https://youtu.be/kbKtFN71Lfs) video.

Currently, my code plots, but each frame is the same frame as the last. I am trying to first plot the vertices, then plot each dot one at a time. The points are precalculated, so all I want is to plot the current point and the points before it. The next step will be for me to make an animation (edit: i.e. gif or mp4), but that is after I can get this part working.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
import random

vertices = np.array([[0,0],
            [2,0],
            [1,2.5]])

dots = 100

def newPos(index, old_x, old_y):
    vertex_x = vertices[index][0]
    vertex_y = vertices[index][1]
    new_x = 0.5*(vertex_x + old_x)
    new_y = 0.5*(vertex_y + old_y)
    return([new_x,new_y])

global points
points = np.array([[0.25, 0.1]])

for i in range(dots-1):
    points = np.concatenate((points, [newPos(random.randint(0,2), points[i][0], points[i][1])]), axis = 0)

plt.figure()

global index
index = 0

def animate(i):
    plt.cla()

    global index
    index += 1

    plt.plot(vertices[0][0], vertices[0][1], 'o')

    global points
    plt.plot(points[0:index][0], points[0:index][1], 'o', color = '#1f77b4')

    plt.legend(['index = {0}'.format(index)], loc='upper left')

    plt.tight_layout()

while index < dots:
    ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=15000/dots)

    plt.title('Chaos Game with {0} Vertices and {1} Steps'.format(len(vertices), dots))

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood how [matplotlib.animation.funcanimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) works, I'll strongly advise you to look at some of the many examples to be found online. Let's try with this version as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import random

vertices = np.array([[0,0],
                     [2,0],
                     [1,2.5],
                     [0,0]])

dots = 1000

# lower and higher bounds for x to be generated
int_lb = np.min(vertices[:,0])
int_hb = np.max(vertices[:,0])

def newPos(index, old_x, old_y):
    vertex_x = vertices[index][0]
    vertex_y = vertices[index][1]
    new_x = 0.5*(vertex_x + old_x)
    new_y = 0.5*(vertex_y + old_y)
    return([new_x,new_y])

# evaluating all your points
points = np.array([[0.25, 0.1]])
for j in range(dots-1):
    points = np.concatenate((points, [newPos(random.randint(int_lb,int_hb), points[j][0], points[j][1])]), axis=0)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([np.min(vertices[:,0])-0.05*np.max(vertices[:,0]),1.05*np.max(vertices[:,0])])
ax.set_ylim([np.min(vertices[:,1])-0.05*np.max(vertices[:,1]),1.05*np.max(vertices[:,1])])
ax.set_title('Chaos Game with {a} Vertices and {b} Steps'.format(a=len(vertices)-1, b=dots))
# draw boundaries
ax.plot(vertices[:,0],vertices[:,1],'k-', linewidth=1)
# initialize scatter object for current step and all evaluated dots
scat_curr = ax.scatter([], [], marker='X', s=15, c='black')
scat_dots = ax.scatter([], [], marker='o', s=5, c='#1f77b4',zorder=-1)

def init():
    scat_curr.set_offsets(np.c_[vertices[0,0], vertices[0,1]])
    scat_dots.set_offsets(np.c_[vertices[0,0], vertices[0,1]])
    return scat_curr, scat_dots

def animate(i):
    scat_curr.set_offsets(np.c_[points[i,0], points[i,1]])  
    scat_dots.set_offsets(np.c_[points[:i,0], points[:i,1]])  
    ax.legend([scat_curr],['iter i = {a}'.format(a=i)], loc='upper left')      
    return scat_curr, scat_dots

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=dots, interval=10)

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

anim.save('some_nice_triforces.mp4', writer=writer)
```

which gives:

[image: triforce]

If you have any questions, I will add some more comments but since this is mainly your own work here I am sure that you will figure out that what you have tried was far more complex than what it should have been :). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to go through what you did and understand it. First of all, why do you use `init_fun` when it works the same without that? Also, I have never used `set_offsets` before because I did not understand the use of it after reading the documentation... Lastly, am I understanding correctly that `np.c_` is essentially the same `np.concatenate` just no need to specify the axis?

Comment: Also, I tried making the code into an mp4 which I have always had issues with. When trying to use FFmpeg, I get the error `RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available`. I have tried all the example codes from online but none of them seem to work so I am at a loss as to why I can't seem to make an mp4 file from my animation...

Comment: I did use init_fun to show you the correct way to initialize your figure if you want to put something else in it at start, set_offsetts is the equivalent of set_data for lines but for scatter object here, and you're right for np.c_. On the other hand,  ffmpeg should be installed, you will find some answer on SO :)

Comment: Hmm, I will keep looking about ffmpeg. I have tried nearly everything, if not everything, that I have found about it, but none of it has worked. Currently stuck with `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` when trying `writer = matplotlib.animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800); anim.save('anim.mp4', writer=writer)`.

Comment: I don't know on Windows but on Linux Mint 19.3, `sudo apt install ffmpeg` works fine with `anim.save('anim.mp4', writer='ffmpeg')`